# Read multiple records from a single line

Tags: r

I want to read data from a file which has the data in form of a key value pair, spread over multiple lines. Please help me read this data into a data.frame.

Data :

```
1:0.344 2:0.0234 3:.6723 5:0.265 9:0245 15:0.309
```

And so on the data spans across multiple lines,

I want the data in the form :

```
 key  value
  1   0.344 
  2  0.0234 
  3   .6723
  5   0.265 
  9    0245 
  15  0.309
```

Comment: You should specify the programming language in the question.

Comment: @Yuval The question is tagged with `r`

Comment: @Yuval-it is tagged R...what else you need

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file with `readLines` and use `strsplit` to split by space and `:`, then convert to a two column `matrix` and wrap it with `as.data.frame`

```
 v1 <- readLines('multiline.txt')
 m1 <- matrix(as.numeric(strsplit(v1, '[: ]')[[1]]), ncol=2,
         byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(NULL, c('key', 'value')))
 d1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
 head(d1,3)
 #  key  value
 #1   1 0.3440
 #2   2 0.0234
 #3   3 0.6723
```